# PostgreSQL: Refactor NOT IN to NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "emails".id,
                "emails".message_id,
                subject, sent_at, sender_contact_id, sender_user_id
  FROM "emails" 
  JOIN "email_participants" ON ("email_participants"."email_id" = "emails"."id")
  LEFT JOIN ranked_replies ON ("emails".id = ranked_replies.email_id AND rnk = 1)
 WHERE ("user_id" = 1) AND ("folder" = 'INBOX')
   AND "emails".message_Id NOT IN (
      SELECT message_id FROM ranked_replies WHERE rnk != 1) 
   AND "emails".id NOT IN (
      SELECT email_id FROM ranked_replies WHERE rnk != 1)
```

I am getting inconsistent results because the NOT IN clause specified below is excluding `NULL`s also:

```
AND "emails".message_Id NOT IN
   (SELECT message_id FROM ranked_replies WHERE rnk != 1)
```

I believe that I could refactor this to `NOT EXISTS` then that would be better:

I have tried this but it errors:

```
AND "emails".message_Id NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT message_id FROM ranked_replies WHERE rnk != 1)
```

I don't think it is possible to specify a field name for not exists.

Can anyone suggest a refactoring so that my `NOT IN` clause works with `NULL`s?

Answer (score 2):

`EXISTS` does not have a left-side operand, it is unary expression. Therefore, 
`EXISTS` makes sense [with correlated subquery](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS), so you need to refer to the outer query from the inner one. Like this:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (
 SELECT 1 FROM ranked_replies WHERE rnk != 1 AND message_id="emails".message_id)
```